# Calculating the time needed to find an sha256 with d zeroes

Tags: hash, sha256

I have a question about simple hashing that I couldn't manage to find to answer on the web.

I am generating random strings, hashing them with sha256 and assume that to find a string that after hashing it has `d` zeroes at it's beginning took me `x` seconds. How can I calclute with `x` how much time it will take me to find a string that after hashing has `d+1` zeroes at it's beginning?

Thanks

Comment: I dont think that is possible.

Comment: Not at all? Because I thought maybe something like this - If I am making random strings, then my sha256 string will be a random as well, and I assume that in is uniform. Then, I have 1/16 probability for getting a '0', so for given d I have (1/16)**d probability for finding a string that it's hash is with d-zeroes at it's beginning. But I cant understand how to translate it to some time-recursive function for finding a d+1 zeroes for a given d zeroes time

Comment: Assume these "zeroes" are 4 zero bits then it will take, on average, roughly 16 times longer to get d+1 zeros than it takes to get d zeros.

Comment: yeah that sounds about right, thank you